# how to make many columns unique in same table

Tags: php, mysql, compiler-errors, phpmyadmin, unique

```
ALTER TABLE  `registered` CHANGE  `Email_ID` UNIQUE KEY ( Email_ID) ) ;
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNIQUE KEY ( Email_ID )' at line 1

Comment: @Dharman It's there, just not formatted properly. Fixed.

Comment: Use [`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html).

Comment: `ALTER TABLE \`registered\` ADD UNIQUE (\`id\`, \`Email_ID\`);`

Comment: Do you mean unique individually or unique as a whole?

Answer (score 0):

The basic query should look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `test1`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`),
  ADD KEY `other` (`other`);
```

for individual unique keys.

A combined key looks like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `test2`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `id_code` (`id`, `code`),
  ADD KEY `other` (`other`);
```

(Note: code for MySQL generated by phpmyadmin)